# Connect the camera module to the PC

Tags: usb, camera, module

I have several camera modules as shown below, but I don't know how to connect them to my PC.
I searched for similar modules and found the camera module [CMT-2MP-IMX291-C014](http://www.camera-module.com/product/2mpcameramodule/2mp-camera-module-sony-starvis-imx291-sensor.html) Using Sensor 1/2.8'' SONY IMX291 Sensor has identical components. However, my output is an 8-pin port, and other modules only have a 4-pin output to USB 2.0 very easily.

[image]

**About the connection pins**

- Pin 1 and 8 is GND
- Pin 3 and 5 is VCC
- The remaining 4 pins I don't know

I have connected the VCC and GND pair to the USB Port, and the two pins D+, D- of the USB I connect to any two of the remaining 4 pins but it doesn't work.
[image]

If you know datasets or how to connect them or any ideas please let me know.
Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: I bought it because they sold it cheap. I usually buy some weird stuff that I don't know about to play with them.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the datasheet for that controller:

https://www.sonix.com.tw/article-en-995-7859

It notes that pin 4 and 5 (dot is pin 1) are the USB +/- data pins. In your picture these are routed next to each other, so presumably connected to something on that connector.

Get a multimeter and probe pin 4/5 and each of the outputs on the connector. Once you know which is USB you can solder on a connector.

Google also turns up open source code for talking to the controller. You may want to look into that.

Comment: Oh, you are the savior of my life.